# Append text to last line, ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

I want to insert text to the last line of current content. It just like an append operation in file. I only find the `editor.insert(text)` method. This method add text right after the cursor. Is there any way just append the text to the last line?

Answer (score 11):

use editor.session.insert method to insert text at arbitrary position

```
var session = editor.session
session.insert({
   row: session.getLength(),
   column: 0
}, "\n" + text)
```